# ROS android_core gradle build error

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ros

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty. Android studio version 1.02
I have installed the indigo flavour of ROS with the intention to install the android_sensors_driver.This also requires installation of android_core.I have all of the required dependencies catkin,rosjava-core,rosjava-build-tools.When I installed the hydro flavour of android_core from the git repository. Then when I ran ./gradlew assemble --stacktrace I get the following error

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_core'.
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find any version that matches org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap:gradle_plugins:[0.1,0.2).
>        Required by:
>            :android_core:unspecified

The stacktrace is:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android_core'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:507)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:82)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:465)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:202)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getFiles(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler.updateClassPath(DefaultScriptHandler.java:75)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:167)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find any version that matches org.ros.rosjava_bootstrap:gradle_plugins:[0.1,0.2).
Required by:
    :android_core:unspecified
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LazyDependencyToModuleResolver$DynamicVersionResolveResult.notFound(LazyDependencyToModuleResolver.java:170)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LazyDependencyToModuleResolver$AbstractVersionResolveResult.resolve(LazyDependencyToModuleResolver.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LazyDependencyToModuleResolver.resolve(LazyDependencyToModuleResolver.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.VersionForcingDependencyToModuleResolver.resolve(VersionForcingDependencyToModuleResolver.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionSelectorResolveState.resolveModuleRevisionId(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:936)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.resolveModuleRevisionId(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:297)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.transform(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.transform(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.create(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:37)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:187)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:102)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:189)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:240)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:230)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:463)
    ... 56 more


BUILD FAILED
```

I have searched for the answer but haven't been able to find anything that solves my problem. I'm completely new to ROS and have limited experience with Linux.
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was struggling with dependancy issues as well.

Try running `./gradlew assemble --info`.

When I had this issue it was because the git maven repository link was outdated, after running `--info` I ended up updating my build.gradle to hardcode the ROS_MAVEN_REPOSITORY variable to:

```
maven {
        url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/master"
    }
```

You can also update the `$System.env.ROS_MAVEN_REPOSITORY` variable to referencethe right maven repository

Also the above URL links to the raw resources for [rosjava mvn repo](https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/)

Comment: Your advice worked perfectly. Now I am stuck again.I followed the readme instructions for the android_sensors_driver. I git cloned the android_sensors_driver repo to my andoid_core folder. I added the line include 'android_sensors_driver' to the settings.gradle file. I changed to the android_sensors_driver directory and ran the command ../gradlew clean debug. I get the following error: Could not find property 'debug' on project ':android_sensors_driver'. This occurs at line 22 ( def rosMavenPath = "$System.env.ROS_MAVEN_PATH".split(':').collect { 'file://' + it })of my gradle.build file.

Comment: I'm also just getting into Ros, what you're facing now is more specific to the actual project (i think), take a look at [answers.ros](http://answers.ros.org/question/197420/compile-android_sensors_driver/). Hopefully that get's you on the right trail. And remember always source the setup file : )

Comment: Thanks for your help.I discovered that I had cloned the old repository. I deleted that and cloned the newer chadrockey fork. included 'android_sensors_driver' in gradle.settings, did a catkin_make while in ~/rosjava as per the readme. ran ./buildAll.sh from android_sensors_driver folder. Got the following error (http://txs.io/yWxb). Googled error,but no help. Line 23 is def rosMavenRepository = "$System.env.ROS_MAVEN_REPOSITORY". Sorry I'm not sure what you mean by "source the setup file"

Comment: That `buildAll` error is looking for Android API 15, is that sdk installed? The where doesn't mean much in this instance, that's just the list of maven directories to find dependencies, look at 'What went wrong'